# How do I target HTML5 with NME and Haxe?

Tags: haxe, nme

I have created the simple NyanCat example project that comes with NME (purely as an example!) using the following line:

```
nme create NyanCat
```

I can compile (target) to Flash and it works, with the following line:

```
nme test project.nmml flash
```

But when I try the same for HTML5, with the following line:

```
nme test project.nmml html5
```

The files are created as expected, the browser appears, but a simple grey box is shown (see image). Firebug suggests the greybox in the image is a Canvas object with opacity set to '1'. There is also a canvas object above and below this one.

Checking through firebug everything is linked (the script files are there). I have tried Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to setup local web server and open generated output from this server, not from filesystem.

On haxeflixel.com forum this subject was discussed lately. But haxeflixel now is down, so I can't post a link.

edit:
Link to topic on haxeflixel.com - http://haxeflixel.com/forum/help/html5-test-page-not-showing-solved

Comment: I ran 'nekotools server' from the folders command line, which enabled me to start a local server. I'm getting a separate problem now, `uncaught exception: DisplayObjectContainer asked to add null child object` But I might ask a separate question for that one